Flink sql - using LAG function with parallelism > 1 does produce expected result
I have the below flink sql code
WITH entitlement_source_hash AS (
        SELECT
            pod, org, tenantId, pk, id, segments, hard_deleted, ts,
            HASH_CODE(tenantId || id || CAST(segments AS STRING)) AS data_hash
        FROM {{ ref('es_entitlement_source') }}
    ),
    entitlement_source_deduped AS (
         SELECT *
         FROM (
             SELECT *,
                    LAG(data_hash) OVER (PARTITION BY tenantId, id ORDER BY ts) AS prev_data_hash
             FROM entitlement_source_hash
             )
         WHERE data_hash IS DISTINCT FROM prev_data_hash OR prev_data_hash IS NULL
    )

SELECT * from entitlement_source_deduped


Here es_entitlement_source has pod, org, tenantId, pk, id, segments, hard_deleted, ts columns.
Gist of the query is

CTE entitlement_source_hash computes the has of 3 columns
CTE entitlement_source_deduped is computing the previous hash using lag function and selection record if previous hash is null or is different from current.
Finally I select from entitlement_source_deduped

The above sql produce right results with result when parallelism is 1. But I dont see any record emitted to kafka when i increase the parallelism > 1.
Note: I send the result of this query to kafka using upsert-connector
How could I fix this ?
